# Sharepoint online Recycle bin. Strange vertical dotted bars running from left to right in the Recycle bin

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image][image: Strange vertical dotted bars running from left to right in the Recycle bin. I think I accidentally clicked "Empty Recycle bin" button and now I have these dotted bars running from left to right for hours. Can anybody explain what they are? and is there any problem?]

Strange vertical dotted bars running from left to right in the Recycle bin. I think I accidentally clicked "Empty Recycle bin" button and now I have these dotted bars running from left to right for hours. Can anybody explain what they are? and is there any problem?

I added a clearer image of the dotted bars

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about. I had it happen to me and I just cleared my cash and they disappeared. Let us know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you Carl. you mean browser cache?

Comment: I cleared browser cache and the dotted bars are still running... Any advise?

Comment: In fact I opened it in another browser (in IE, before it was Chrome ) and the dotted bars are still running...